# gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Not supported

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, gnupg, raspbian, gpg-agent

I am building a script that is using `msmtp` to send myself regular system reports by email. I have used `gpg` to encrypt my email password and used `password-eval` in `msmtp.conf`.

I sent a test email successfully but during the process, `gpg` asked me for the passphrase I used to create keys when I `gpg --full-generate-key`.

Given that the script will be running unattended, I need to cache the passphrase using `gpg-preset-passphrase`. However when I run `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset <keygrip>` where keygrip is obtained using `gpg --list-keys --with-keygrip`, I get the error message: `gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Not supported`.

For reference, I am using `gpg 2.2.12` on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running Raspbian Buster.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 5):

This feature must first be enabled in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` using the option:

```
allow-preset-passphrase
```

After editing the config it might be enough to `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`, or you might need to restart the agent completely.

Note that the preset passphrase is only stored in memory – it will not persist across reboots. (How would gpg-agent store it securely, anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

Nice thread that gave me the final steps for my automated loading GPG key with passphrase into gpg-agent:

In my context, I've a single GPG key already installed in the .gnupg folder.
Everything is done inside the following bash function: `gpg_agent_preset()`

Other functions are DRY code to avoid duplication. ;-)

`gpg-connect-agent -q 'keyinfo --list' /bye` give the keygrip ID in my context. If your context has more that one GPG key, you can obtain the keygrip with `gpg --fingerprint --with-keygrip <email>`

could look like:

```
gpg --fingerprint --with-keygrip EMAIL_OF_GPG_KEY_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR | awk '/Keygrip/ { print $3}'
```

NOTE: `/usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase` is not in the PATH.

```bsh
error()
{
  >&2 echo "error:$*"
}

check_envvar()                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
{
  local envvar_name=$1
  # ${!varname} indirect value in bash
  if [[ -z ${!envvar_name} ]]
  then
    error "\$$envvar_name is empty"
    return 1
  fi
}

gpg_agent_preset()
{
  local gpg_passphrase="$1"
  # authorize preset mechanism, in our context agent is not loaded yet.
  echo allow-preset-passphrase  >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

  # this will start the agent ang give use keygripID
  local keygrip=$(gpg-connect-agent -q 'keyinfo --list' /bye | awk '/KEYINFO/ { print $3 }')

  # output looks like
  #S KEYINFO B1A955E910AEFAAB2FAD9EADBFAA5C59AFAAF0AA D - - - P - - -
  #S KEYINFO AAA2AAE20FCB9621D22BAFEE1C0AA2B011AA6AA6 D - - - P - - -
  #OK

  local k
  for k in $keygrip
  do
    echo "$gpg_passphrase"  | /usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset $k
  done
}
```

have fun!